# How to get height and width of viewport without creating scrollbars?

Tags: jquery, height, width, scrollbars

Trying to extend an HTML `canvas` across an entire page, but the jQuery `width()` and `height()` functions are creating vertical and horizontal scrollbars.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <canvas id="bg_canvas" width="" height=""></canvas>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Expand canvas to full viewport size
    var vp_width = window.clientWidth;
    var vp_height = window.clientHeight;

    $("#bg_canvas").css({
        "width" : vp_width,
        "height" : vp_height
    });

// Canvas Drawing
    var canvas = document.getElementById("bg_canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="#cbf7ed";
    ctx.fillRect(100,100,vp_width,100);
```

Also tried the Javascript `window.innerheight` and `window.innerWidth`, but that also creates scrollbars.

Comment: Is `vp_width` returning the (/a) correct value? You could also try using CSS: `#bg_canvas{width:100vw;height:100vh;}`.

Answer (score 0):

The default browser stylesheet is likely giving the `<body>` element a margin. Because, the canvas is within the body, that would make the canvas larger than its parent, creating a scrollable view.

If you want the canvas to span the width of the window, remove margin and padding from the body element via CSS. You can verify this with inline styling: `<body style="margin:0 padding:0">` (though its generally best practice to place styling in discrete files or at least in the html header).

Alternatively, if you want the canvas to span the body, use something like:

```
var vp_width = $('body').innerWidth;
var vp_height = $('body').innerHeight;
```

Comment: Thank you! That appears to be it. I've now added a position: absolute on the canvas, bypassing the body. Thanks again!